# Turn instances into bounding boxes or proxies in the viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes, procedural, point-clouds

I am currently doing a large scale scene involving scattering tons of trees. The viewport slows to a crawl then I do so, is their a way to convert the meshes into bounding boxes when in the viewport but when it is rendered it renders the full res model?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use **is viewport** and **switch** nodes like this:

[image]